# How to output the index number of a list within a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that holds a list that holds multiple values in them, I'm supposed to have a show method to output the dictionary in this format

```
"
2017-02-12:
    0: Eye doctor
    1: lunch with sid
    2: dinner with Jane
2017-03-29:
    0: Change oil in blue car
    1: Fix tree near front walkway
    2: Get salad stuff
2017-05-06:
    0: Sid's birthday"
```

however, with my code, I'm only able to get it to display like this

```
2017-02-12:
    Eye doctor
    lunch with sid
    dinner with Jane
2017-03-29:
    Change oil in blue car
    Fix tree near front walkway
    Get salad stuff
2017-05-06:
    Sid's birthday
```

I have no idea how to get the index number to display before the value itself. How would I do that?
This is my current code

```
def command_show(calendar):
    for i in calendar:
        print("    "+ i +":")
        for l in calendar[i]:
            print("        ", l)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
calendar={'2017-05-06': ["Sid's birthday"], '2017-03-29': ['Change oil in blue car', 'Fix tree near front walkway', 'Get salad stuff'], '2017-02-12': ['Eye doctor', 'lunch with sid', 'dinner with Jane']}

for i in calendar:
    print("    "+ i +":")
    count=0
    for l in calendar[i]:
        print("        ", str(count)+":",l)
        count+=1
```

output:

```
2017-05-06:
     0: Sid's birthday
2017-02-12:
     0: Eye doctor
     1: lunch with sid
     2: dinner with Jane
2017-03-29:
     0: Change oil in blue car
     1: Fix tree near front walkway
     2: Get salad stuff
```

Comment: Thank you, this method works! Much appreciated it, would you know how to also to encapsulate this output into a str, I just realized it needs to be in this format. I have edited the actual output format above.

Answer (score 0):

```
def command_show(calendar):
    for key, value in calendar.items():
    print(key + ':\n')              
    for l in calendar[key]:         
        print("    " + str(list(calendar[key].keys()).index(l)), calendar[key][l])
```

Explanation:

prints the calendar date:

```
 print(key + ':\n')
```

Iterates over the nested dict of each date:

```
 for l in calendar[key]:
```

Make a list of nested dict keys from each date:

```
 list(calendar[key].keys())
```

Get the index of the key:

```
 str(list(calendar[key].keys()).index(l))
```

Comment: Don't just blurt out code! Adding some text to describe how this code best answers the question will improve the long-term quality of the answer and help to prevent it from being deleted during review.

Comment: @NightOwl888: Added. Thank you.